# GAE appspot.com is blocklist?

Tags: google-app-engine

Using GAE mail service to send mails.while sending mail to one of ours. I have issue  like as below.

Technical details of permanent failure:Google tried to deliver your message, but it was  rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 5.7.1 rejected content, black listed XXXXXX.appspot.com by dbl.dnsbl. #762 #895 (o7F1ZY023821731400) (state 17).

so we look out **spamhaus** URL : http://www.spamhaus.org/dbl/removal/record/appspot.com
In that url

DBL record for appspot.com
The domain name appspot.com is listed on the Spamhaus DBL.

appspot.com has been listed in the DBL because it is a spammer abused URL shortener or redirector.

If you are an authoritative administrator of appspot.com and you have solved the abuse issues you can write to us at dbl-mmxi@spamhaus.org from either abuse@appspot.com or postmaster@appspot.com and inform us of the actions you have taken to clean up the current spammer URLs. Please also inform us of any steps you have taken to prevent future abuse of your shortener/redirector. We will review your request and, at our discretion, remove the listing or respond to your request.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is there offical supporting team in google app engine

Comment: There is an issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: thankyou for your information.Hope it will help us.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are to [report the issue to Google](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) so they can try to get removed from the black list or you can switch to using a different service for sending email from App Engine.

I cannot vouch for the best external email sending service as I do not have experience with them all but some of the ones others have suggested on the mailing list are Amazon Simple Email Service, Sendgid, and Message Bus. [See discussion here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/6KzdGoCw7ZQ/discussion).

Comment: thank you. We have submitted to Google issue list. Regarding your comment about email sending service, please note the comment given below in response to Bert's comments.

Comment: @thangavel OK, I misread what was going on. Assuming there is a reason you are not already using your own domain for your app (SSL cost?) there are strategies that will allow you to not have an appspot URL in the email but still have that be the location the user is sent when they click the URL. The simplest are redirection tricks like URL shorteners but you could create a handler on your own domain that if called with parameters like `http://somedomain.com/handler?v=dasf67&c=2` simply redirects the user to the final URL `https://someapp.appspot.com/handler?v=dasf67&c=2`

Comment: thank you. we are looking into these options, i.e. avoiding appspot.com as part of the contents by having a url shortener or having a handler in ourdomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

You should send mail from appengine using address name@appid.**appspotmail**.com not @appspot.com. 
Here are details on sending mail.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail

**Sending mail from a custom domain:**
If you are sending mail from custom domain, make sure you setup spf record and dkim for that domain.

To see how to setup SPF record, have a look at http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723

To see how to setup a DKIM record, have a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview#DKIM

Also, for a bit more background about issues of sending mail, read this great post from Jeff Attwood http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

**In response to comments**:
Regarding .appspot.com domain being blacklisted by SpamHaus, can you setup a domain for your appengine app instead of using the appid.appspot.com url and see that this solves your problem?

Comment: we have used google app engine **email address** to send email.even though we have issue

Comment: @thangavel, according the your post, the address is name@xxxx.appspot.com not name@xxxx.**appspotmail**.com.

Comment: please note, we send out emails from user@ourdomain.com and ourdomain.com is NOT an appid.appspot.com domain. However, we send a hyperlink in the email which is an URL on appid.appspot.com. The email is being identified as a SPAM by SPAMHAUS **NOT** beacuse of the sender id, i.e. user@ourdomain.com, but because of appspot.com hyperlink contained within the email.

Comment: @thangavel, if you are sending mail as user@ourdomain.com, from within appengine, make sure you setup spf and dkim records (as outlined in the answer above). Also, instead of the hyperlink pointing to appspot.com, can't you make it point at ourdomain.com?

Comment: 1.Apologies for the inconvenience, but please help us to understand this better. 1) our emails are not being rejected by the Gmail servers and the link you provided mostly talks about recipients on Gmail server. 2) are you saying SPAMHAUS may not reject the emails if we create an SPF record and / or signing with DKIM? please note SPAMHAUS is identifying our emails as spam NOT because of the "from" address, but because the body of email contains an URL that has appspot.com as a part of it. Please see http://www.spamhaus.org/dbl/removal/record/appspot.com.

Comment: 2.The reason we say our emails are identified as spam NOT because of the "from" address is because the error message clearly says the "black listed content" (please see highlighted entry below):

Technical details of permanent failure:Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 5.7.1 **rejected content, black listed <app-id>.appspot.com by dbl.dnsbl. #762 #895** (o7F1ZY023821731400) (state 17).

Comment: 3.This (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/ou-UTj5YKVk) is another example where an email with appspot.com content is rejected by SPAMHAUS.

Comment: I couldn't add more than 600 characters per one comment. So i split into three comments. Please see above three comments.